# PHP: Cannot upload ZIP Files

Tags: php, file-upload, zip

Whenever I try to upload a ZIP File via PHP, the Filesize is 0.

Everything else works: 7z, rar, png, xml

for example (I output filesize and location for testing):

```
File Location: /tmp/phpKNortG/feba81fed1ff5d2c04aa0c42975eb94f.7z
Filesize: 1284


File Location: /tmp/phpEWrmLT/feba81fed1ff5d2c04aa0c42975eb94f.zip
Filesize: 0
```

My form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and the file is definitely not too big to be uploaded. (I've also set the memory limit to 128 MB to make sure it's not that)

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
set_time_limit(0);

$session_id = "3423840093480344";

mkdir('uploaded_files/' . $session_id);

for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['backup_file']['name']); $i++) {
    $file_name = $_FILES['backup_file']['name'][$i];
    $file_type = $_FILES['backup_file']['type'][$i];
    $file_error = $_FILES['backup_file']['error'][$i];
    $file_size = $_FILES['backup_file']['size'][$i];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['backup_file']['tmp_name'][$i];

    print($file_name . "<br />");
    print($file_type . "<br />");
    print($file_error . "<br />");
    print($file_size . "<br />");
    print($file_tmp . "<br />");

    if($file_error != 0) {
        echo "Error-Code: ".$file_error;
        continue;
    }

    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'uploaded_files/' . $session_id);
}
```

The following code outputs this:

```
feba81fed1ff5d2c04aa0c42975eb94f.zip
application/zip
0
0
/tmp/phpEWrmLT
```

It even recognizes the MIME-Type, but the file is always zero bytes in size. (even before moving it with move_uploaded_file)

Is there any server setting that could prevent .zip files to be uploaded?

Comment: Is this your server? Any chance, it's running Suhosin?

Comment: Nope. Also my Server Specs: Ubuntu 64 Bit with Apache/2.2.14. My PHP Version is: 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.1

Comment: How did you fix this? Having the same problem!

Comment: I ended up doing this, and it worked for me: "In php.ini or in the separate configuration file suhosin.ini, look for a "suhosin.session.cryptua" setting and set it to Off." (by Daemon of Chaos)

Answer (score 1):

The memory_limit setting has no bearing on file uploads.

What are the values for your post_max_size and upload_max_filesize and how does the .zip filesize compare with those values?

Comment: I already edited these. They're both 4000 MB (I was really desperate) and I already tried several different ZIPs each with different sizes. (From 1 KB to 4 MB)

Comment: How much available space do you have in /tmp? Also, what is the actual size of the .zip file you are trying to upload?

Comment: That cannot be the problem. I'm constantly uploading other stuff, and I'm trying to fix this error for over a month. The actual zip file size I used for testing 1.32 kb

Comment: Have you tried changing the .zip file's extension and then uploading it? If so, what were the results.

Comment: Hmm.. the file uploads normally if I use a different extension. The MIME-Type seems to make no difference. Maybe it's some kind of Firewall or Anti-Virus thingy?

Comment: In php.ini or in the separate configuration file suhosin.ini, look for a "suhosin.session.cryptua" setting and set it to Off.